# How to change PushButton border radius

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I want to change border radius of my PushButton lesson1

Tried to create a class Button with setStyleSheet in __init__ and create an object.

```py
import sys

from pyto import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.lesson1 = Button()


class Button(QtWidgets.QPushButton):

    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super(Button, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setStyleSheet('border-radius: 15px;')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = MyWin()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

No errors, but setStyleSheet doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code `self.ui.lesson1 = Button()` does not replace the self.ui.lesson1 created by Qt Designer, it only causes the new `Button()` to be assigned to the name `self.ui.lesson1`. So if you want to set the stylesheet it is not necessary to create another class:

```
# ...

class MyWin(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtWidgets.QWidget.__init__(self, parent)
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        # self.ui.lesson1 = Button()
        self.ui.lesson1.setStyleSheet('border-radius: 15px; background-color: red;')

# ...
```

<sup>I have added the background color to make the radius visible.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for explanation!